# Particular Solution of ODE 2?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

today I found an interesting example considering viscoelasticity. While I was solving the given ODE I wondered, how the authors came to the solution they gave ... (the thing I am talking about is example 5.(b) at the last page of [this script](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_I/BookSM_Part_I/10_Viscoelasticity/10_Viscoelasticity_03_Rheological.pdf).)

The ODE that is considered is given by:

$$ (\eta_1 + \eta_2)\cdot\dot\epsilon + \frac{E_1+E_2}{E_1\cdot E_2}\cdot\ddot\epsilon = \sigma_0 $$

where $\sigma_0, \eta_1, \eta_2, E_1, E_2$ are constants. It's not difficult to find the homogenous solution that has the form of:

$$\epsilon_H(t) = C_1 + C_2\cdot e^{\lambda_2 \cdot t}$$

In **5. (b)** they write

> Consider now a constant stress $\sigma_0$. By using the condition that only the springs react at time t = 0, show that the particular solution is $\sigma_0\cdot t/(\eta_1+\eta_2)$.

To get the particular solution I make an ansatz: $\epsilon_P = A \rightarrow \dot\epsilon_P = \ddot\epsilon_P = 0$. Putting this in the ODE, we get $0 = \sigma_0$ what is actually not true.

If I assume that $\epsilon_P = A\cdot t + B \rightarrow \dot\epsilon_P = A, \ddot\epsilon_P = 0$ and put this in the ODE, I get $(\eta_1 + \eta_2)\cdot A = \sigma_0 \rightarrow A = \frac{\sigma_0}{\eta_1 + \eta_2}$ ... and finally $\epsilon_P = \frac{\sigma_0}{\eta_1+\eta_2}\cdot t$ which I was looking for.

I always thought that If there's a constant disturbing "function", I have to take an constant ansatz. (If the disturbing function is linear, I take an linear Ansatz etc.) ... where's the mistake in my thoughts?

It would be fine if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!